# Spring boot Json crudRepository empty post type request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am working on a REST api project with Spring boot, in my POJO class "book" I create a table entity to be mapped by hibernate:

```
package com.libreria.proyect.libreria_el_aleph.model;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Libro")
public class Libro {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID_libro")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
private Integer idLibro;

@Column(name = "ISBN")
private String isbn;

@Column(name = "Nombre_libro")
private String nombreLibro;

@Column(name = "Autor")
private String autor;

@Column(name = "Precio")
private Double precio;

@Column(name = "Cantidad")
private int cantidad;


public Libro(Integer idLibro, String isbn, String nombreLibro, String autor, Double precio, int cantidad ){
    
    this.idLibro = idLibro;
    this.isbn = isbn; 
    this.nombreLibro = nombreLibro;
    this.autor = autor;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.cantidad = cantidad;

}


/**
 * @return Integer return the idLibro
 */
public Integer getIdLibro() {
    return idLibro;
}

/**
 * @param idLibro the idLibro to set
 */
public void setIdLibro(Integer idLibro) {
    this.idLibro = idLibro;
}

/**
 * @return String return the isbn
 */
public String getIsbn() {
    return isbn;
}

/**
 * @param isbn the isbn to set
 */
public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
}

/**
 * @return String return the nombreLibro
 */
public String getNombreLibro() {
    return nombreLibro;
}

/**
 * @param nombreLibro the nombreLibro to set
 */
public void setNombreLibro(String nombreLibro) {
    this.nombreLibro = nombreLibro;
}

/**
 * @return String return the autor
 */
public String getAutor() {
    return autor;
}

/**
 * @param autor the autor to set
 */
public void setAutor(String autor) {
    this.autor = autor;
}

/**
 * @return Double return the precio
 */
public Double getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}

/**
 * @param precio the precio to set
 */
public void setPrecio(Double precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
}

/**
 * @return int return the cantidad
 */
public int getCantidad() {
    return cantidad;
}

/**
 * @param cantidad the cantidad to set
 */
public void setCantidad(int cantidad) {
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
}
```

}

I'm trying to post to the get method that implements CrudRepository in my controller, but when I make a test request the content of all the Json elements comes back empty, how can I fix this?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("Api/libros")
public class LibroController {

    @Autowired
    LibroServices service; <-- Here is my repository crud service

    @GetMapping("/AllBooks")
    public ResponseEntity<ArrayList<Libro>> getAllBooks(){
        ArrayList<Libro> getAllBooks = this.service.listar();
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(getAllBooks);
    }

    
    @PostMapping("/AllBooks")
    public ResponseEntity<Libro> createNewBook(@RequestBody Libro libro){
        Libro createNewBook = service.saveNewBook(libro); 

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(createNewBook) ;
    }
}
```

[image]

As a request I also add the content of my services file:

```
package com.libreria.proyect.libreria_el_aleph.model.Services;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List; 
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.libreria.proyect.libreria_el_aleph.model.Libro;
import com.libreria.proyect.libreria_el_aleph.model.
InterfaceServices.ILibroServices;
import 
com.libreria.proyect.libreria_el_aleph.model.Interfaces.ILibro;

@Service
public class LibroServices implements ILibroServices {

@Autowired(required = true)
ILibro repository; 

@Override
public ArrayList<Libro> listar() {
    return (ArrayList<Libro>) repository.findAll();
}

@Override
public Optional<Libro> listarById(Integer idlibro) {
    return Optional.empty();
}

@Override
public Libro saveNewBook(Libro libro) { <-- save method
    return repository.save(libro);
}

@Override
public void delete(Integer idLibro) {
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in your save method, whatever you are inserting i think its not saved in database. First check that the data is reflecting in database.

Comment: My model seems to be correctly nested to the database, I created a schema sql file and added some test inserts and everything went fine, something is going wrong when sending the data via the save method parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a constructor without id field like below in your Pojo :

```
public Libro(Integer idLibro, String isbn, String nombreLibro, String autor, Double precio, int cantidad ){
    
    this.idLibro = idLibro;
    this.isbn = isbn; 
    this.nombreLibro = nombreLibro;
    this.autor = autor;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.cantidad = cantidad;

}
```

Also, post a object without Id as you have set @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
It will auto generate the ID.

Also, don't create the variable name same as method name . Try changing it to something else like:

```
@PostMapping("/AllBooks")
    public ResponseEntity<Libro> createNewBook(@RequestBody Libro libro){
        Libro book = service.saveNewBook(libro); 

    return ResponseEntity<>(book,HttpStatus.CREATED) ;
}
```

Comment: If this doesn't works. Do share your service method too where you are doing the save operation.

Comment: I have made the suggested changes and still see no changes. I just added my services file.

Comment: Then only thing which seems to be wrong is that your request body mapping object is unable to store the values in it.       Are you sending the json object same as the name of the variables in your entity. Like { "isbn": "hello"}.   The field name should refer to you entity not your SQL column names

Answer (score 0):

see here you are sending list of data from postman and in your method you are receiving one object so if you want to save multiple data the use this in controler

```
@PostMapping("/AllBooks")
public ResponseEntity<Libro> createNewBook(@RequestBody List<Libro> libro){
    Libro createNewBook = service.saveNewBook(libro); 

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(createNewBook) ;
}
```

and in service use :

```
@Override
public List<Libro> saveAllNewBook(List<Libro> libros) { <-- save method
    return repository.saveAll(libro);
}
```